# localStorage: I can't remove an item using @ngx-pwa/local-storage

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

I have a link in a angular 6 webapp and when I click it i want to use `removeItem` ( the item is `dateFilter`) from the Local Storage. I'm using [@ngx-pwa/local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage)

**My method in my app.components.ts**

```
 clearFilter(){       
    this.storage.removeItem('dateFilter').subscribe(() => {});
  }
```

**My HTML app.component.html**

```
 <li *ngIf="user.storeOwner || menu.includes('report_employees')">
   <a class="sub-links" (click)="sendToPage('/employees-report', langs.reports + ' > ' + langs.professionals); clearFilter()">
     {{langs.professionals || 'Profissionais' }}
   </a>
 </li>
```

When i click everything works fine, but it doesn't remove the item `dateFilter` and doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I think you are checking directly from developer tools. What happens when you check it from store.getItem('dateFilter')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of competition with the method `clearFilter()` and `SendToPage` and I call the `sendToPage` inside the `storage` method like that:

**HTML (inside the click)**

```
 (click)="clearFilter('/employees-report', langs.reports + ' > ' + langs.professionals)"
```

**Method:**

```
 clearFilter(url, desc){
    this.storage.removeItem('dateFilter').subscribe(() => {
      this.sendToPage(url, desc);
    });
  }
```

And i pass the parameters to the method to remove the item before `sendToPage`